# AngularJS Finding all Hidden Input in a scope WITHOUT Jquery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

What is a way of finding all hidden input in a scope of a controller? And ideally can this be done when the controller is initizialied?

In my example I have mutliple comments like this:

```
 <div ng-controller="CommentCtrl">
         <form method="post">
              <label>Leave Comment</label>
              <textarea name="comment" ng-bind="comment"></textarea>

              <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="1" />
              <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="2" />
         </form>
    </div>
```

So I the init, I only want to iterate through scope to find the hidden values of that controller and then assign it a value. Is there a way I can do this in AngularJS?

Comment: Deal with DOM in controller isn't the angular way, you should consider using model in controller to drive your view.

Comment: It will. The process of initialize the model is searching through the values in the controller. After the model has been initialized it handles the other interactions. So is there a way?

Comment: So the initial value of your model is from those hidden fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you really **need** to access those hidden fields within your controller (which is not good a practice with angular, as @Ye Liu said above) try angular.element("input[type=hidden]"); It will give you a list with all the hidden inputs. You need to have jquery linked up in your html file before angularjs script.

Comment: This wouldn't work because I would only want to current scope

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a directive so you can access the DOM in the proper way.

### Option 1

Create a directive that you put on the top DIV. In the link function of this directive, you can access the DOM element and find all hidden inputs.

```
link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
   angular.forEach(iElement.find('input'),function(inputElement) {
      if(inputElement.attr('type') == 'hidden') {
        // do something
      }
   });
}
```

This is using [jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element), which comes with Angular.

### Option 2

Do something similar as Angular does with [input](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput) and simular directives: create a directive based on standard HTML. So you could create a directive named 'type', restricted to attributes.